# Is there a way to get eclipse to automatically detect a space/tab mismatch the way Visual Studio does?

Tags: ide, visual-studio, eclipse, code-formatting

In Visual Studio 2010, when I open a source code file that has a mix of tabs and spaces, a message will appear warning me as such and give me a chance to correct it.  Is there such a feature in Eclipse whether native or via plugins?

Comment: you can select the whole thing and press `ctrl-I` or just `ctrl-shift-F` to format everything (the resulting format is customisable)

Comment: That's not exactly what I want to do.  The problem with that is that it formats everything.  I simply want to fix the space/tab mix.

Comment: you can just do a replace of `"    "` with `"\t"` in each file

Comment: That's what I *could* do, but the question isn't "How do I replace tabs with spaces?"  The question is, "How do I have my IDE automatically detect when there is a formatting problem?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, this is not as nice as Visual Studio's solution and very similar to the answer above, but here's how I resolved this.

1. Go to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors
2. Check the box "Show whitespace characters"
3. Click on "Configure Visibility"
4. Check the boxes under the Leading column for Ideographic space and Tab
5. Check the boxes under the Trailing column for Space, Ideographic space, and Tab
6. All other boxes should be unchecked.
7. "Ok" everything.  You may have to reopen existing windows for this to take effect.

If you prefer having your code tabbed instead of using spaces, then you'll slightly modify these instructions to show leading spaces instead of leading tabs.  In any case, having this set up as such gives me instant visibility when I have a file that uses tabs instead of spaces or mixed tabs and spaces.

I would not recommend using CTRL+SHIFT+F as it makes for a subversion nightmare when diffing old and new code.  Alternatively, simply do a CTRL+F, check the Regex box, replace \t with four spaces.  You'll still see a lot of diffs in subversion, but it's easy to pick out that you simply updated the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I have not noticed such a feature, but there are settings you can change so you can detect it yourself. Essentially I show whitespace characters (specifically tabs and spaces). To show whitespace characters:

```
Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Show whitespace characters
```

Click on the "whitespace characters" link to modify which whitespaces characters to show.

Then modify your language formatters to enforced tabs over spaces (or vice versa). Then when you format code (Ctrl+Shift+F) it will enforce the convention you set in your formatter. This has the other side effect of formatting the rest of your code, but that might not be a bad thing.

If you want to remove trailing whitespace when you format your code, you can do that by editing your "Clean Up" profile and clicking the "Remove trailing whitespace" option int the "Code Organizing" tab